# Circuit breaker Trips during thunderstorm

Tags: electrostatics, electricity, electric-circuits, everyday-life

The circuit breaker at the electrical mains trips at home when there is a thunderstorm outside. Why does this occur?

Comment: I suspect this can be found via a search engine.

Comment: It happens to avoid dangerously high voltages to reach the equipment behind the breaker, thus avoiding damage to TV sets, computers and so on.

Answer (score 2):

For a given amount of resistance (combined resistance of all the circuits in your computer, or home, or city), the amount of current which flows is proportional to the voltage.  (I=V/R)

When lightning strikes a line, it induces a voltage spike.  Traditional circuit breakers are current-sensing devices (whether solid state or electromechanical).  So, a temporary spike in voltage (V) will, for a fixed resistance (R), create a temporary spike in current (I).  If the spike is big enough, it trips the circuit breaker.

In the pre-electronics age, conventional (electromechanical) circuit breakers were good enough, because they could trip fast enough to prevent excessive heating and thus fires.

Unfortunately, modern electronics can be destroyed by a voltage pulse within microseconds, long before an electromagnetic circuit breaker can trip.  Thus, the need for solid state (usually MOV-based) surge protectors.

A little history on the MOV, in case you're interested:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CiBXN82vzNQ